# Login validation with mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, validation, authentication

i'm starting to learn mongo to create a small login form validation. Currently i'm stuck at this point where I am trying to compare my username received from the POST req with the value in the database, the sample code i came in my mind is the one below.

```
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
username = req.body.username;
password = req.body.password;
MongoClient.connect(urldb, function(err, db){
    var dbo = db.db('LCC');
    var query = {_id: username, password: password}
    var output = dbo.collection('Users').find(query)
    if(output == username){
        console.log('Found');
    }else{
        console.log('Not found');
    }
    db.close();
    res.end();
});
```

});

I'm not so sure if the find method used is the best/suitable for this case, but looks like it works, the question is how i work with the object that is returned to me when I do this .find(query)? This is the one to compare or I'm totally in the wrong direction?

Just posted this sample because I think is enough, but if needed I'll show more. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are multiple problems in your code

change your query from this

`var query = {_id: username, password: password}`

to

`var query = {username: username, password: password}`

then instead of using `.find(query)` use `.findOne(query)` because find returns array of objects.

then because the query is [asynchronous](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) you should't assign it like `var output = dbo.collection('Users').find(query)` instead use a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) function like this

```
  dbo.collection('Users').find(query, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw new Error(err);
      if(!user) 
        console.log('Not found');
      else 
        console.log('Found!');
  })
```

you seem like you are new to node.js too. go to w3school https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_query.asp to get more basic understanding of how node and mongodb works